# Citrix workspace app 2009 webcam and mic not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam, citrix, zoom-meeting

I installed [Citrix Workspace app 2009 for Linux](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html) (deb package). And the Zoom plugin. It works fine, multi monitor etc. When I connect to a Zoom call in the Citrix session (Windows 10), it shows one frame of video and then the video freezes (I hear the relay in the webcam click on and then again for off).

I can see this is `/var/log/syslog`, repeated once a second:

```
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:16 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: EUEM ROUNDTRIP wdica:EmulQueryInformation:WdUserActivity
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: ===CamPoll===
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: WdQueryInformation(76): rc=0x0
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: CGPrecv: got 3 bytes (err 11) (stream 0)
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: CGPCore: CgpDataArrived entered.
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: CGPCore: CgpDataArrived exiting with status: 0x2.
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: TcpRecv: ipLayer 0xc48200, AmountRead=3
Oct 29 11:20:17 my-machine citrix-wfica[105906]: TcpRecv: ipLayer 0xc48200, rc=0
```

The Windows 10 Camera app says that no camera was detected, so I'm guessing video is streaming from the local Citrix Zoom plugin over TCP.

Any ideas appreciated, I can't get any more useful information out of Citrix or Zoom locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Turns out I was using the wrong version of the Zoom VDI plugin. The version of zoom on my virtual desktop is 5.0.23901.6522. In this case I had to install version 3.0.5 (5.0.469977.0929) of the plugin.

Comment: Yep - my org updated Zoom on my virtual desktop a few days ago. It all works now.